# Cumulative sum by day with non-negative floor with PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, aggregate, window-functions, running-totals

Using PostgreSQL 12, I need to calculate the cumulative sum by day while filling in missing days. I *also* need to set a minimum value of `0` if any cumulative sum goes negative.

#### Background

There are two excellent answers for [cumulative sum with missing days](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32490946/cumulative-sum-of-values-by-month-filling-in-for-missing-months?noredirect=1&lq=1) and [non-negative floor values](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/179367/set-non-negative-floor-for-rolling-sum-in-postgresql). I need to combine these two solutions.

Take this table and data as an example (note, this is also contained in [this db fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=e84c62c5b4e95ebdd4c027b5f241a21f))

```sql
CREATE TABLE inventory_test (
    "id" serial,
    "account_id" bigint NOT NULL,
    "is_active" boolean NOT NULL DEFAULT 'true',
    "object_timestamp" bigint NOT NULL,
    "amount" numeric(12, 1) NOT NULL,
    "object_id" bigint NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY ("id")
);
```

*Note that `object_timestamp` is epoch time in milliseconds

```sql
SELECT id, to_timestamp((object_timestamp + 0 )/1000), amount
FROM inventory_test
ORDER BY object_timestamp;
```

| id | to_timestamp | amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-04-08 15:13:30+01 | 10000.0 |
| 2 | 2022-04-09 15:13:30+01 | -2000.0 |
| 3 | 2022-04-09 15:13:31+01 | -1000.0 |
| 4 | 2022-04-10 15:13:30+01 | -2000.0 |
| 5 | 2022-04-11 15:13:30+01 | -3000.0 |
| 6 | 2022-04-12 15:13:30+01 | -2500.0 |
| 7 | 2022-04-15 15:13:30+01 | -2500.0 |
| 8 | 2022-04-16 15:13:30+01 | -3000.0 |
| 9 | 2022-04-17 15:13:30+01 | 1000.0 |

I can generate the daily totals accounting for missing days with:

```sql
WITH cte as (
    SELECT 
        date_trunc('day', to_timestamp((object_timestamp)/1000)) as day,
        sum(amount) as day_sum
    FROM inventory_test
    WHERE object_id = 1 AND is_active = true
    GROUP by 1
    )
SELECT 
    day, 
    sum(c.day_sum) OVER (ORDER BY day) AS running_sum
FROM 
    (SELECT min(day) AS min_day FROM cte) init,
    generate_series(init.min_day, now(), interval '1 day') day
LEFT   JOIN cte c USING (day)
ORDER  BY day;
```

| day | running_sum |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-04-08 00:00:00+00 | 10000 |
| 2022-04-09 00:00:00+00 | 7000 |
| 2022-04-10 00:00:00+00 | 5000 |
| 2022-04-11 00:00:00+00 | 2000 |
| 2022-04-12 00:00:00+00 | -500 |
| 2022-04-13 00:00:00+00 | -500 |
| 2022-04-14 00:00:00+00 | -500 |
| 2022-04-15 00:00:00+00 | -3000 |
| 2022-04-16 00:00:00+00 | -6000 |
| 2022-04-17 00:00:00+00 | -5000 |

#### DB fiddle

You can see this in [this DB fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=e84c62c5b4e95ebdd4c027b5f241a21f)

#### Desired results

What I *want* the results to look like are non-negative, where any positive changes are applied to the adjusted running total which should be `MAX(0, running_sum)`. I'd prefer to solve this in a SQL statement rather than a custom function.

Desired output:

| day | running_sum |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-04-08 00:00:00+00 | 10000 |
| 2022-04-09 00:00:00+00 | 7000 |
| 2022-04-10 00:00:00+00 | 5000 |
| 2022-04-11 00:00:00+00 | 2000 |
| 2022-04-12 00:00:00+00 | 0 |
| 2022-04-13 00:00:00+00 | 0 |
| 2022-04-14 00:00:00+00 | 0 |
| 2022-04-15 00:00:00+00 | 0 |
| 2022-04-16 00:00:00+00 | 0 |
| 2022-04-17 00:00:00+00 | 1000 |

Comment: Hi, and welcome to dba.se! Could you please put your data in the DDL format (i.e. `INSERT INTO my_table  VALUES (.....` This removes the possibility of error and eliminates duplicatoin of effort on the part of those trying to answer. Help us to help you! :-)

Comment: Go to dbfiddle.uk and construct one therre!

Comment: Thank you! DB fiddle added.

Comment: I'm a bit puzzled. You have an initial 10,000 - then -2,000 but your running sum goes to 7,000. Why not 8,000? The first two dates?

Comment: There are two rows which represent the same day. The row with timestamps `1649513610000` and `1649513611000`. These are merely 1s (1000ms) apart on `2022-04-09`. Sum up the values (-2000 + -1000) results in 10000-3000 = 7000 on `2022-04-09`

Comment: That's not what I'm seeing. Check the new bit of the fiddle marked with my handle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=0ff6b4855730eace45f79a2fb4fb1849).

Comment: One of the rows was out of order...check the fiddle again as I added and `order by` which makes it more obvious. Apologies for the confusion!

Comment: Can't find the new fiddle with the two transactions on the same date? Could you post it into the question please?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135637/discussion-between-brianz-and-verace).

Answer (score 2):

In order to answer this, I did the following (all of the code below can be found on the fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=3019114d5897507871239dba439410f6)):

The data can be found on the fiddle, so I'll just start on the SQL:

My first step was to create a calendar table - they really are very handy, take up little space and make the SQL much cleaner. Of course, the dates can be generated dynmically if that's a requirement.

So, my first pass at the SQL was this:

```
WITH c1 AS
(
  SELECT
    c.d,
    COALESCE(SUM(it.amount), 0) AS s
  FROM calendar c
  LEFT JOIN invtest it
    ON c.d = to_timestamp(it.object_timestamp/1000)::DATE
  WHERE c.d BETWEEN '2022-04-08' AND '2022-04-17'
  GROUP BY c.d 
  ORDER BY c.d 
), c2 AS
(
  SELECT
    d,
    CASE  
     WHEN SUM(s) OVER (ORDER BY d) <= 0 THEN 0
      ELSE SUM(s) OVER (ORDER BY d)
    END AS the_SUM
  FROM c1
)
SELECT 
  d,
  the_sum
FROM c2;
```

Result:

```
d   the_sum
2022-04-08  10000.0
2022-04-09  7000.0
2022-04-10  5000.0
2022-04-11  2000.0
2022-04-12  0
2022-04-13  0
2022-04-14  0
2022-04-15  0
2022-04-16  0
2022-04-17  0
```

Not bad for a first pass - but the devil is in the detail - Pareto's Principle tells us that we get 80% of the result with 20% of the effort - it's getting to that 100% that costs us way more...(i.e. 80% more1) as was the case in this particular endeavour! There were extra requirements which arose in the chat which proved challenging to say the least.

My next effort was this:

```
SELECT 

  d, 
  the_sum,
  
  
 CASE WHEN
(SELECT  amount 
  FROM invtest WHERE TO_TIMESTAMP(object_timestamp/1000)::DATE = t2.d 
  AND t2.the_sum = 0)> 0
  then
 (SELECT  amount 
  FROM invtest WHERE TO_TIMESTAMP(object_timestamp/1000)::DATE = t2.d 
  AND t2.the_sum = 0)
  
  ELSE 0
  END AS whatever

FROM
(
WITH c1 AS
(
  SELECT
    c.d,
    COALESCE(SUM(it.amount), 0) AS s
  FROM calendar c
  LEFT JOIN invtest it
    ON c.d = to_timestamp(it.object_timestamp/1000)::DATE
  WHERE c.d BETWEEN '2022-04-08' AND '2022-04-17'
  GROUP BY c.d 
  ORDER BY c.d 
), c2 AS
(
  SELECT
    d,
    CASE  
     WHEN SUM(s) OVER (ORDER BY d) <= 0 THEN 0
      ELSE SUM(s) OVER (ORDER BY d)
    END AS the_SUM
  FROM c1
)
SELECT 
  d,
  the_sum
FROM c2) AS t2;
```

Result:

```
d   the_sum     whatever
2022-04-08  10000.0     0
2022-04-09  7000.0  0
2022-04-10  5000.0  0
2022-04-11  2000.0  0
2022-04-12  0   0
2022-04-13  0   0
2022-04-14  0   0
2022-04-15  0   0
2022-04-16  0   0
2022-04-17  0   1000.0
```

The last individual being the only person with a negative `the_sum` who received a positive amount! This is signifcant, because the requirement in this case was that if someone had a negative `the_sum`, but received a positive amount, their sum went to that amount and wasn't just simply added to their "debt".

Anyway, to cut to the chase, here's the final SQL.

```
SELECT 
  d, 
  COALESCE(CASE 
    WHEN the_sum > 0 THEN the_sum
    WHEN
      (SELECT amount 
       FROM invtest 
       WHERE TO_TIMESTAMP(object_timestamp/1000)::DATE = t2.d 
       AND t2.the_sum = 0)> 0
    THEN
      (SELECT  amount 
       FROM invtest 
       WHERE TO_TIMESTAMP(object_timestamp/1000)::DATE = t2.d 
       AND t2.the_sum = 0)
  END, 0)::INT AS the_sum
FROM
(
WITH c1 AS
(
  SELECT
    c.d,
    COALESCE(SUM(it.amount), 0) AS s
  FROM calendar c
  LEFT JOIN invtest it
    ON c.d = to_timestamp(it.object_timestamp/1000)::DATE
  WHERE c.d BETWEEN '2022-04-08' AND '2022-04-17'
  GROUP BY c.d 
  ORDER BY c.d 
), c2 AS
(
  SELECT
    d,
    CASE  
     WHEN SUM(s) OVER (ORDER BY d) <= 0 THEN 0
      ELSE SUM(s) OVER (ORDER BY d)
    END AS the_SUM
  FROM c1
)
SELECT 
  d,
  the_sum
FROM c2) AS t2;
```

Result:

```
d           the_sum
2022-04-08  10000
2022-04-09  7000
2022-04-10  5000
2022-04-11  2000
2022-04-12  0
2022-04-13  0
2022-04-14  0
2022-04-15  0
2022-04-16  0
2022-04-17  1000
```

Et voilà - as the OP desired! All the gory details are to be found in the fiddle  [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=3019114d5897507871239dba439410f6) (the final answer is at the end - as one might expect! ;-) ).

Comment: This is very close. The issue is that I need to calculate the running total through `now()`. Changing the `WHERE` clot to `WHERE c.d BETWEEN '2022-04-08' AND now()` results in the last rows return 0, where there are no inventory changes. In my scenario I need those to be the running total value, which is `1000` in this example.

Comment: If I've understood you correctly, you want to include the dates from 2022-04-17 to NOW() - even though there have been no changes to amount - so the numbers remain the same, you just want to display them through to 2022-04-21 9 (today's date)?

Comment: Or have I got that wrong?

Comment: Exactly. The use case is inventory. However there are times when inventory levels drop below `0` and in that case we need is merely assume `0`, rather than negative. So the daily inventory level will be the last positive value calculated. If we have an inventory level of `1000` and 7 days pass with no changes, the inventory level is still `1000` for each of those 7 days with no activity.

Comment: @brianz - important question - is there always an amount, even it it's `0` or can there be `NULL`s ?

Comment: No, there is not an inventory entry every day. If nothing occurs we can assume a zero change for that day as I had in one of my initial queries. It may help to think about your banking account. You start with an opening balance, and each day you can have debits or credits. Many days you will have no credits or debits, but you still have an account balance. The problem statement is akin to, "Design a query which shows account balance by day, accounting for days with no activity and ignoring any balances which go below zero."

Comment: @brianz - was this answer correct?